# google unable to retrieve stock with "." or ":" characters in name

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-datareader

I a trying to get data of 'NSE:MRF' stock from google finance using python , but it is throwing an error :

```
RemoteDataError('Unable to read URL: {0}'.format(url))
RemoteDataError: Unable to read URL: http://www.google.com/finance/historical?q=NSE%3AMRF&startdate=Jan+01%2C+2012&enddate=May+05%2C+2017&output=csv
```

Please tell me the solution of this problem , I suppose this issue is not new , i tried no of things suggested on different threads , but nothing worked .

Thanks

Comment: Are you able to access that url in a browser?

Comment: have you tried using raw string?

Comment: I guess google finance didn't recognize NSE as the indian stock market, if I remove `NSE%3A`, it works fine.

Comment: I don' think issue is with colon as http://www.google.com/finance/historical?q=NASDAQ:AMZN&startdate=Jan+01%2C+2012&enddate=May+05%2C+2017&output=csv works fine . Also https://www.google.com/finance/historical?q=NSE%3AMRF does not have the export "download to spreadsheet" button

Comment: I tried to download data from yahoo finance then also it throws same kind of error :(

Comment: @Ding If I just give MRF , then it wrongly gets the data of different tock , not the indian stock .

Answer (score 1):

From https://support.google.com/finance/answer/71913?hl=en

> The option to download to spreadsheet varies by exchange and may not be available for all stocks.